# Punctuation when clarifying a time period (e.g. late January - early February)

Tags: punctuation

Which one is correct or, at least, more common and advisable?

> late January - early February
>
> late January — early February
>
> late January-early February
>
> late January—early February

Comment: I'd most likely go for **late January/early February**, but a slash could be interpreted as meaning "or", so wouldn't be appropriate if only "to" worked in the context - so for "late January - early April", I would probably type it like your first option (which Microsoft Word would autocorrect to "late January – early February").

Comment: The difference between dashes can easily be looked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a whole can of worms.

The orthodox answer is that the en dash - the dash with the same width as the capital N: '–', is correct. People argue about what is acceptable / best / in use in which context / should be in use / etc - a whole lot more than is probably good for anyone.  Almost no one takes the time to write en dashes when typing on a computer.  Although there are keyboard shortcuts for it, they're not widely used and some older software will not deal with them well.

The short answer is: if you are writing professionally, refer to your style guide, it will tell you which dash to use. If you are not writing professionally, most readers will not care so much.

The third option is probably the most "normal" of the four, but since the endpoints contain multiple words, perhaps consider something like:

> late January to early Fabruary

Comment: Which of my suggestions is the best?

Comment: Even if you were writing professionally, your editor or proofreader would presumably correct your submission... which isn't to say that people shouldn't make an effort, but traditionally the length of dashes was something that only printers and typographers worried about.   It isn't a question of punctuation, strictly speaking, only of typographical convention. But with the advent of modern computing we've all become amateur typographers to some extent - just as many people were amateur calligraphers in an earlier age.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - None of those are an en dash above.  I would just use the '-' character without spaces between the items and the dash (the third option).  It might be even better to say "late January to early February" here explicitly however, since it's a little weird to have '-' connect ranges that have multiple words for each endpoint.

Comment: @rjpond Yup!  Style guides have definitely changed to concern themselves with more of the typographical aspects of orthography in response. But I suppose you also need to select a dash length when /handwriting/.  (Remember that? My hands sure don't...)  I confess I have never thought about making the proper N-width dash when writing by hand.